# How can I display my mongoDB query as json using express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I use nodemon to start my express server, it constantly loads in the browser and will not load any of my application. 
This is the code in my dbconn.js and app.js files. I cannot figure out how to pull and display my query in order to verify my connection to the db. I am a total beginner in using mongoDB and express. Please help. 
It is not throwing any exceptions, so I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const uri ='mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@wager0-mhodf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });

client.connect(err => {


    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

 
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        const collection = client.db("wager0").collection("gameTypes");
        // Get first two documents that match the query
        collection.find({a:1}).limit(2).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});

      });
      
    client.close();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
var dbconnRouter = require('./services/dbconn');

app.use('/dbconn', dbconnRouter);
```

Comment: have you tried printing `docs`. and try using res.send insted of res.json.

Comment: when you say printing docs, are you just referring to the print() method? Also I will try the res.send this afternoon.